# Yii Refresh Grid On DropDown change

Tags: drop-down-menu, yii

In YII views folder i have test module and  admin.php file to manage contents are below and i render form here where i put the code of form and dropdown in it , i want that grid refresh value of status change in dropdown 
Suppose i select "Approved" than Grid show the data where status is approved

```
    <?php
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('dropdown', "

$('.dropdown-form form').submit(function(){
$('#testimonial-grid').yiiGridView('update', {
        data: $(this).serialize()
    });
    return false;
});
");
?>
<h1>Manage Testimonials</h1>
<div class="dropdown-form">
<?php $this->renderPartial('_dropdownform',array(
    'model'=>$model,
)); ?>
</div><!-- search-form -->
    <?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'testimonial-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
    'filter'=>$model,
    'columns'=>array(
        'id',
        'created_by',
        'test_name',
        'test_email',
        'comments',
        'created_at',
        /*
        'status',
        'approved_on',
        'approved_by',
        */
        array(
            'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
        ),
    ),
)); ?>
```

Form below is _dropdownform , it contain a form and dropdown from this dropdown i am choosing the value of status

```
<div class="wide form">
    <?php
    $form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
        'action' => Yii::app()->createUrl($this->route),
        'method' => 'get',
    ));
    ?>
    <div class="row">
        <?php
        echo CHtml::dropDownList('status', '', array(0 => 'New', 1 => 'Approved', 2 => 'Declined'), array(
            'prompt' => 'Select Status',
            'ajax' => array(
                'type' => 'POST',
                'url' => Yii::app()->createUrl('testimonial/loadthedata'), 
                //or $this->createUrl('loadcities') if '$this' extends CController
                'update' => '#testimonial-grid', //or 'success' => 'function(data){...handle the data in the way you want...}',
                'data' => array('status' => 'js:this.value'),
        )));
        ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row buttons">
<?php //echo CHtml::submitButton('Search');   ?>
    </div>
        <?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
</div><!-- search-form -->
```

AND THE CODE IN MY CONTROLLER OR URL GIVEN IN DROPDOWN TO FETCH DATA IS FOLLOWING ACTION BUT I DONT KNOW HOW TO FETCH DATA FROM THIS FUNCTION AND PASS TO GRID VIEW

```
public function actionloadthedata() {
    if (isset($_POST['status'])) {
        $status = $_POST['status'];
       if($status==0){
           $status='New';
       }
       if($status==1){
           $status='Approved';
       }
       if($status==2){
           $status='Declined';
       }
        Testimonial::model()->findByAttributes(array('status'=>$status));


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use CGridView property [filterCssClass](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CGridView#filterCssClass-detail) to link the grid filter, for example

```
$this->widget('CGridView', array(
    'id' => 'my-list',
    'filterCssClass' => '#filterFormId .filter',
```

And there is filter form

```
<?php $form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id' => 'filter-fomr-id',
)); ?>

<div class="filter clearfix">
    <?php echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'name', [0=>'all', '1'=>'some else']); ?>
</div>
```

Replace #filterFormId .filter on jquery selector specific to you form. In other words, set id attribute for filter form, then use "#THISID .row".

Comment: Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #testimonial-grid .#filter-fomr-id .filter input, #testimonial-grid .#filter-fomr-id .filter select

Comment: set some Id to filter form, then use #THISID .row

Answer (score 1):

In your gridview file, make sure you have this code:

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('search', "
$('.search-button').click(function(){
    $('.search-form').toggle();
    return false;
});
$('.search-form form').submit(function(){
    $('#ad-grid').yiiGridView('update', {
        data: $(this).serialize()
    });
    return false;
});
");
```

then in the CGridView definition:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'testimonial-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
    'filter'=>$model,
    'columns'=>array(
        ...
        array(
            'name'=>'Status',
            'filter'=>CHtml::dropDownList('YourModel[status]', $model->status, array(0 => 'New', 1 => 'Approved', 2 => 'Declined'), array('empty' => '--all--') ),
            'value'=>'( $data->status == 0) ? "New": ( $data->status == 1) ? "Approved" : "Declined"',
            'htmlOptions' => array(
                'style' => 'width: 40px; text-align: center;',
            ),
        ),
        ...
        array(
            'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
        ),
    ),
));
// CGridView
```

In order to save if/else in the `'value'` section, you can implement a method in your model that returns the string associated to the integer.

It works great, just with the default [Yii admin.php view](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/353/working-with-cgridview-in-admin-panel/), which you can edit as much as you need.

**Update**
Added support for empty status, does not filter query results

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Alex for your help but i am successful to make filterdropdown for grid , code is following but will you please tell me that i want that grid show only values where status=New , how i can do when page load grid show values where status is New
but first i paste the working code of dropdown filter for grid
Here is my admin.php file

```
    <?php
$this->breadcrumbs = array(
    'Testimonials' => array('index'),
    'Manage',
);
$this->menu = array(
    array('label' => 'List Testimonial', 'url' => array('index')),
    array('label' => 'Create Testimonial', 'url' => array('create')),
);
?>
<h1>Manage Testimonials</h1>
<!-----------drop down form------------->
<?php
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('dropdownfilter', "

$('.dropdown-form form #staticid').change(function(){
    $.fn.yiiGridView.update('testimonial-grid', {
        data: $(this).serialize()
    });
    return false;
});
");
?>
<div class="dropdown-form">
    <?php
    $this->renderPartial('_dropdownfilter', array(
        'model' => $model,
    ));
    ?>
</div><!-- search-form -->
<?php
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id' => 'testimonial-grid',
    'dataProvider' => $model->search(),
   // 'filter' => $model,
    'columns' => array(
        'id',
        'created_by',
        'test_name',
        'test_email',
        'comments',
        'created_at',
        'status',
        array(
            'class' => 'CButtonColumn',
        ),
    ),
));
?>
```

Here is my render partial form where i place the static drop dow

```
<div class="wide form">
<?php
$form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'action' => Yii::app()->createUrl($this->route),
    'method' => 'get',
));
?>
<div class="row">
    <?php
    echo CHtml::dropDownList('staticid', '', array('0' => 'New', '1' => 'Approved', '2' => 'Declined'), array(
        // 'onChange' => 'this.form.submit()',
        'ajax' => array(
            'type' => 'POST', //request type
    )));
    ?>
</div>
<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
```

And Here is code of my adminaction in controller

```
public function actionAdmin() {
    $model = new Testimonial('search');
    $model->unsetAttributes();  // clear any default values
    if (isset($_GET['staticid'])) {
        $getStatus = $_GET['staticid'];
        if ($getStatus == 0)
            $status = 'New';
        if ($getStatus == 1)
            $status = 'Approved';
        if ($getStatus == 2)
            $status = 'Declined';
        $model->status = $status;
    }
    if (isset($_GET['Testimonial']))
        $model->attributes = $_GET['Testimonial'];
    $this->render('admin', array(
        'model' => $model,
    ));
}
```

Now i want that when i actionadmin triggered first time it show status=New values

Comment: In actionAdmin controller add after $model-> unsetAttributes(); $model-> status = 'New';